# workflow that sends a reminder 10 days before start date field

Tags: workflow, powershell, email

I am trying to create a `workflow` that sends a `reminder` to the director  approver in case he does not approve it 10 days before start date field.

Here is how I initially though it:

> If current item status is equal to director approval
>
> Add -10 days to start date
>
> Output variable notify date
>
> Wait until variable: notify date
>
> Send email to director

technically this would work but the problem is if in the meantime the director does approve the form he will still get this notification.

What I also thought is the possibility of using a powershell script to run daily through this `list` and process every item according to these conditions.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional status kind of field like `isAlreadyApproved` ans set it no to default.When the director approves set it to yes.

Then check after `wait until` action with a if condition `isAlreadyApproved` is no then only send mail else skip.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra check for the `Status==Director approval` in the workflow, after the wait action and before the email sending action.